# Return a value from vectors in a list using only column names

Tags: r, list, vector, nested

Consider the following list.
This list (named "list1" in this example) contains three named vectors "A", "B", and "C". Each of those vectors have two columns, which are always named "one" and "two":

```
> list1
$A
     one      two 
2005.015 1339.938 

$B
      one       two 
1.0000075 0.1815634 

$C
          one           two 
-66264.148352     -2.868802
```

Say I want to get the value of the column "two" from the vector "B". There are three ways I know how to do this:

```
list1[[2]][[2]]
list1$B[[2]]
list1[[2]]$two
```

However this is **not** a way to get that value:

```
list1$B$two
```

Is there any way to get this value using only the column names, rather than column indexes?

Comment: If you think I'm not correct about those not being frames, then please [edit] your question and paste the output from `dput(nested_df)` (as I did in my answer). Thanks!

Comment: You were right about them being lists and I edited my question to follow the terms you used instead.

Comment: It is still not nested lists, just a list with vectors. In R, there is a difference between a vector and a list, and how to subset it by-name is one of those differences.

Comment: Noted and added to the question - sorry about the confusion around naming. In my head I treat all these things very similarly.

Comment: Each programming language treats lists/vectors/tables/frames/arrays/matrices slightly differently, part of the challenge when learning new languages is to understand how the new language differs from your understanding and assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those do not appear to be nested frames, nor frames at all: it appears to be a `list` of named numeric vectors. Here's what I suspect the data is:

```r
nested_df <- list(A=c(one=1,two=2), B=c(one=11,two=12), C=c(one=21,two=22))
nested_df
# $A
# one two 
#   1   2 
# $B
# one two 
#  11  12 
# $C
# one two 
#  21  22
```

As such, you can use

```r
nested_df$B["two"]
# two 
#  12
```

Raw data:

```r
nested_df <- list(A = c(one = 1, two = 2), B = c(one = 11, two = 12), C = c(one = 21, two = 22))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the vectors inside the list to either a data.frame or a list.

```r
lst <- list(A = c(one = 2005.015, two = 1339.938),
            B = c(one = 1.0000075, two = 0.1815634),
            C = c(one = -66264.148352 , two = -2.868802))

lst <- lapply(lst, function(.x) data.frame(A = .x[[1]], B = .x[[2]]))

lst$A$A
#> [1] 2005.015
lst$B$A
#> [1] 1.000007

lst <- lapply(lst, function(.x) list(A = .x[[1]], B = .x[[2]]))

lst$A$A
#> [1] 2005.015
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>